# How do I check if file is a named pipe in perl?

Tags: perl, file, named-pipes, fifo

Kind of like:

```
-e /path/to/file or die "file doesn't exist";
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
-p /path/to/pipe or die "not a valid pipe";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed use `-p` (see [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) for all the filetest operators available in Perl).

Comment: Ugh, the website I was using didn't name all the options. Thanks for your help, official perldoc only now.

Comment: @MaxMackie: What's the web site?